# Add new rows to resultset in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am running a SQL query in MSSQL 2008 R2 which should always return a consistent resultset, meaning that all dates within a selected date range should be shown, although there are no rows/values in the database for a particular date within the date range. It should for example look like this for the dates 2013-07-03 - 2013-07-04 when there are values for id 1 and 2.

**Scenario 1**

```
Date-hour, value, id
2013-07-03-1, 10, 1
2013-07-03-2, 12, 1
2013-07-03-...
2013-07-03-24, 9, 1
2013-07-04-1, 10, 1
2013-07-04-2, 10, 1
2013-07-04-...
2013-07-04-24, 10, 1

2013-07-03-1, 11, 2 
2013-07-03-2, 12, 2
2013-07-03-...
2013-07-03-24, 9, 2
2013-07-04-1, 10, 2
2013-07-04-2, 12, 2
2013-07-04-...
2013-07-04-24, 10, 2
```

However, if id 2 is missing values for 2013-07-04, I will normally only get a resultset which looks like this:
**Scenario 2**

```
Date-hour, value, id
2013-07-03-1, 10, 1
2013-07-03-2, 12, 1
2013-07-03-...
2013-07-03-24, 9, 1
2013-07-04-1, 10, 1
2013-07-04-2, 10, 1
2013-07-04-...
2013-07-04-24, 10, 1

2013-07-03-1, 11, 2 
2013-07-03-2, 12, 2
2013-07-03-...
2013-07-03-24, 9, 2
```

Scenario 2 will create an inconsistent resultset which will affect the output. Is there any way to make the SQL query always return as scenario 1 even when there are missing values, so at least to return NULL if there are no values for a specific date within the date range. If the resultset returns id 1 and 2 then all dates for id 1 and 2 should be covered. If id 1, 2 and 3 are returned then all dates for id 1, 2 and 3 should be covered.

I have two tables which look like this:

```
tbl_measurement
    id, date, hour1, hour2, ..., hour24

tbl_plane
    planeId, id, maxSpeed
```

The SQL query I am running look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hour00_01, hour01_02, mr.date, mr.id, maxSpeed 
FROM tbl_measurement as mr, tbl_plane as p 
WHERE (date >= '2013-07-03' AND date <= '2013-07-04') AND p.id = mr.id 
GROUP BY mr.id, mr.date, hour00_01, hour01_02, p.maxSpeed
ORDER BY mr.id, mr.date
```

I have been looking around quite a bit, and perhaps PIVOT tables are the way to solve this? Could you please help me out? I would appreciate if you can help me out with how to write the SQL query for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate a list of dates.  If you `cross join` that with planes, you get one row per date per plane.  With a `left join`, you can link in measurements if they exist.  A `left join` will leave the row even if no measurement is found.

For example:

```
declare @startDt date = '2013-01-01'
declare @endDt date = '2013-06-30'

; with  AllDates as
        (
        select  @startDt as dt
        union all
        select  dateadd(day, 1, dt)
        from    AllDates
        where   dateadd(day, 1, dt) <= @endDt
        )
select  *
from    AllDates ad
cross join
        tbl_plane p
left join
        (
        select  row_number() over (partition by Id, cast([date] as date) order by id) rn
        ,       *
        from    tbl_measurement
        where   m.inputType = 'forecast'
        ) m
on      p.Id = m.Id
        and m.date = ad.dt
        and m.rn = 1 -- Only one per day
where   p.planeType = 3
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: When I run this query, I get the error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@startDt".". Where do I declare this? Where do I add my date range into this? Is this to be used in combination with my current query, not sure that I understand.

Comment: Did you include the `declare` lines when you ran the query?  You can replace `@startDt` and `@endDt` with a hard-coded value if that's what you prefer.

Comment: Nice, it's working well and is what I am looking for. The only thing that I'd like to adjust (which I left out of the original description for simplicity) is to also filter the values returned so that only p.planeType = '3' and m.inputType = 'forecast' are included. I tried to add this after "...and m.date = ad.dt and p.planeType = '3' and m.inputType = 'forecast'" but it still returns all rows. also tried with "...and m.date = ad.dt where p.planeType = '3' and m.inputType = 'forecast'" but then it does not work anymore. Where could I add this filtering?

Comment: The plane condition goes in a `where` clause.  The measurement filtering goes in the join condition (after `on`.)  If you'd put the measurement condition in the `where` clause, you'd filter out dates without a matching measurement.

Comment: Nice, working exactly as it should now. Thank you Andomar for a great solution.

Comment: @Andomar Maybe slightly off topic for this question, but wouldn't this fail for date ranges > 100 days? I seem to remember that that's the default recursion limit.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Not if you add `option  (maxrecursion 0)` at the end

Comment: @Andomar Ah, true, missed that one :)

Comment: If there are 2 or more identical p.Id, can I get the query to only return 1 of them per day?

Comment: @Andomar - If there are 2 or more identical p.Id, can I get the query to only return 1 of them per day?

Comment: How would you choose the 1 row?  Can it be a random row?

Comment: @Andomar - Yes, the row can be random as the query only returns the p.Id which are relevant. So the resultset would only contain one p.Id per day.

Comment: Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Updated the answer to limit to one measurement per day